# Pytorch RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory at loss.backward() , No error when using CPU

Tags: out-of-memory, pytorch

I'm training a Fully convolutional network (FCN32) for semantic segmentation on Tesla K80 with more than 11G memory.

The input image is pretty large: 352x1216. Network structure is shown below. I used *batch_size=1*, but still encounter the 
out_of_memory error.

Criterion is nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

The network works fine when I run on CPU.

---

```
    Layer (type)               Output Shape       #  Param 
        Conv2d-1        [-1, 64, 352, 1216]           1,792
        Conv2d-2        [-1, 64, 352, 1216]          36,928
     MaxPool2d-3         [-1, 64, 176, 608]               0
        Conv2d-4        [-1, 128, 176, 608]          73,856
        Conv2d-5        [-1, 128, 176, 608]         147,584
     MaxPool2d-6         [-1, 128, 88, 304]               0
        Conv2d-7         [-1, 256, 88, 304]         295,168
        Conv2d-8         [-1, 256, 88, 304]         590,080
        Conv2d-9         [-1, 256, 88, 304]         590,080
    MaxPool2d-10         [-1, 256, 44, 152]               0
       Conv2d-11         [-1, 512, 44, 152]       1,180,160
       Conv2d-12         [-1, 512, 44, 152]       2,359,808
       Conv2d-13         [-1, 512, 44, 152]       2,359,808
    MaxPool2d-14          [-1, 512, 22, 76]               0
       Conv2d-15          [-1, 512, 22, 76]       2,359,808
       Conv2d-16          [-1, 512, 22, 76]       2,359,808
       Conv2d-17          [-1, 512, 22, 76]       2,359,808
    MaxPool2d-18          [-1, 512, 11, 38]               0
       Conv2d-19         [-1, 4096, 11, 38]     102,764,544
       Conv2d-20         [-1, 4096, 11, 38]      16,781,312
       Conv2d-21          [-1, 1, 11, 38]           4,097  ConvTranspose2d-22         [-1, 1, 352, 1216]             4,096
```

---

Error message:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        36         print (loss)
>        37         #torch.cuda.empty_cache()
>   ---> 38         loss.backward()
>        39         optimizer.step()
>        40
>
> /anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/tensor.py in
>   backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
>        91                 products. Defaults to `False`.
>        92         """
>   ---> 93         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
>        94 
>        95     def register_hook(self, hook):
>
> /anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/autograd/**init**.py
>   in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
>   grad_variables)
>        88     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
>        89         tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
>   ---> 90         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
>        91 
>        92
>
> RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory

Comment: This happens on `loss.backward` because the back propagation step may require much more VRAM to compute than the model and the batch take up. Provided this memory requirement only is brought about by `loss.backward` you won't necessarily see the amount needed from a model summary or calculating the size of the model and/or batch. Further, this works in CPU land because, if you have an seemingly modern computer, you most likely have 32GB of RAM // A good way to view this information is with tensorboard or equivalent, it can/will show memory usage throughout training and pre step.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this happens because of **memory on your GPU**. If you have more powerful GPUs, your problem could be solved (as you mentioned in your answer).
But if you do not have, you can **scale down your images** into about `256*x` sizes.
It is also good practice for **performance**'s sake.

Comment: I was using Microsoft Azure which gave me a Tesla K80 with more than 11G memory. The error occurs when I used only ~2G of it. Could it be related to the cloud that someone might be assigned to the same GPU with me?

Comment: It depends on which version of Azure you are using. I do not know about Azure, but it could be related.

Comment: I would also go the route of simply resizing the images. At one point in the network there is 102,764,544 parameters, most probably the cause of the OOM error

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason... It's hardware related. I changed to another machine and the error disappeared.